# Why I can't get the ClientContext by OM in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Here is what I did in my project:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("before");
  //It can not work cause the LIST is in the subsite called "Service"
  //var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var context =new SP.ClientContext("http://sp2010dev1:88/Service/");
  alert(context );  
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

But, the alert(context) can not execute ,when I check the concole it showed me `TypeError: SP.ClientContext is not a constructor`,that is to say there was something wrong with the initialization of ClientContext.  Why?   How can I get ClientContext?  Or was it caused by the lacking of SP.js?

My Final Solution is : Add this statement to the masterpage:  ,and then everything works good!    May this can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing directly in the `<script>` blocks try to insert in the `function` and call that function on body load.

Another good way is call using the jquery

```
$(document).ready()(function(){
var context =new SP.ClientContext("http://sp2010dev1:88/Service/");
  alert(context );  

});
```

Try this once, even if it is not working then will try to find another solution.

Along with this as per steve suggestion, include first `sp.js` and perform remaining things.

Comment: Isn't sp.js load by SharePoint by default?  It is works by add some code to load sp.js!

Comment: Once you have a sharepoint site the sp.js will automatically load. If you want to check whether the `sp.js` is loaded or not, goto developer tools in the IE and goto script tab and search for `sp.js`, you will find it.

Comment: I did have a SharePoint site . But it seems do not load the  sp.js , so confused

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it probably is because SP.js is not loaded. Try this:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="SP.js" Localizable="false" OnDemand="False" LoadAfterUI="True"></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        /* your code here */;
    }, "sp.js");
</script>
```

Comment: It worked now , but the delaying of operating by OM is not looks so good